cat/sort/uniq temporary storage?
I'm wondering where this data is being stored. I am running these commands from a different file system, but / seems to increase and I'm not sure where the data is.
cd /different_fs
cat a b c | sort | uniq > new.file
df shows / increasing
Is sort or uniq creating a temp file somewhere? it's not in memory or /tmp that I can tell.
The files are 70+ GB and the server has 8 GB memory. Also df shows the space increasing and the command ultimately failed "No Space on Device".

It's in memory.

the files are 70+ GB and the server has 8 GB memory. Also df shows the space increasing and the command ultimately failed No Space on Device...not sure the exact words

Both sort and uniq (which is usually also sort - certainly using both is redundant when sort already supports a unique option) overflow to the filesystem. You can see where the files go using lsof when processing a large, slow file (optionally throttling the output).

Since uniq processes already sorted data / checks adjacent lines only, it should not require a temporary file. For sort, see https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html regarding temporary files.
